# NSTableView don`t display NSTableCellView instantiated from xib

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I have *view* based on `NSTableView` with custom cell view (`NSTableCellView` subclass - it is also set in the Attributes inspector as a custom class). `NSTableCellView` is created from xib.

1. Firstly in  `viewDidLoad` I do

   ```
   NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"ApplicationInfoView" bundle:nil];
   [self.tableView registerNib:nib forIdentifier: @"ApplicationInfoView"];
   ```
2. In the *dataSource* method `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` I do:

   ```
    ApplicationInfoView *infoView = [aTableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"ApplicationInfoView" owner:self];
   ```

It is instantiated but the table doesn't show anything, although while scrolling, I can see in logs that the cells are created correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my bad.
I should have to use `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` instead of `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`, which i chose automatically from data source (lets call it iOS to OSX syndrome).
Still do not understand why `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is in delegate but not in data source.